# Excel VBA: alter url based on cell value

Tags: vba, excel, web-scraping

Parent post:
[VBA: Selecting from dropdown menu to reload page and scraping data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50091708/vba-selecting-from-dropdown-menu-to-reload-page-and-scraping-data/50092106#50092106)

Apparently I don't know how to use stackoverflow: I deleted my profile, thinking I was 'muting' the email updates. Just started coding VBA today, not quite sure what I'm doing. With the help of the awesome user SIM, the code is working.

I was trying to further tinker the code, to alter the web url address such that it would insert whatever ticker symbol I put in cell J1. In this case, I'm trying to lookup more than just jpm.

The goal here is to put in whatever ticker symbol in J1, and it would be reflected on the query url.
For example:
J1 would hold AAPL, and the .Open command would be

```
.Open "POST", "https://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/jpm/historical", False
```

Or J1 would hold WFC, and the .Open command would be

```
.Open "POST", "https://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/WFC/historical", False
```

However, my attempts are not working so hot.
Here's what I have so far.

```
Sub Get_Data()
    Dim tabd As Object, trow As Object, r&, c&
    Dim QueryString$, S$

    QueryString = "10y|false|" & Range("J1").Value & "" ''change here the "year" and the "ticker" name as necessary
    ''Set web_url = "https://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/" & Range("J1").Value & "/historical"

    Range("A:F").ClearContents

    With New XMLHTTP
        .Open "POST", "https://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/jpm/historical", False
        ''.Open "POST", "web_url", False
        .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "IE"
        .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
        .send QueryString
        S = .responseText
    End With
    With New HTMLDocument
        .body.innerHTML = S
        For Each tabd In .getElementById("quotes_content_left_pnlAJAX").getElementsByTagName("table")(0).Rows
            For Each trow In tabd.Cells
                c = c + 1: Cells(r + 1, c) = trow.innerText
            Next trow
            c = 0: r = r + 1
        Next tabd
    End With

End Sub
```

I commented out the section that did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, your commented part is almost right. You can't use `Set` since you are creating a string, and the ticker inside the url must be lower case. Also, you were passing `"web_url"` as string literal in the `Open` method.

This is how you would do it:

```
Sub Get_Data()
    Dim tabd As Object, trow As Object, r&, c&
    Dim QueryString$, S$

    QueryString = "10y|false|" & Range("J1").Value & "" ''change here the "year" and the "ticker" name as necessary
    web_url = "https://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/" & LCase(Range("J1").Value) & "/historical"

    Range("A:F").ClearContents

    With New XMLHTTP
        .Open "POST", web_url, False
        .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "IE"
        .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
        .send QueryString
        S = .responseText
    End With
    With New HTMLDocument
        .body.innerHTML = S
        For Each tabd In .getElementById("quotes_content_left_pnlAJAX").getElementsByTagName("table")(0).Rows
            For Each trow In tabd.Cells
                c = c + 1: Cells(r + 1, c) = trow.innerText
            Next trow
            c = 0: r = r + 1
        Next tabd
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: wow, got it! So to make sure I got this right, I don't need to make web_url a string by using the quotation marks "" because it is already a string? In addition, url must all be lowercase, so a uppercase messes things up, thus needing a LCase(stuff) to correct for that?

Comment: @EKC As you didn't `Dim web_url`, it is by default a `Variant` type which can pretty much anything. As a good practise in VBA, you should `Dim web_url As String` or `Dim web_url$`. The `$`,`&`, etc are just short forms. Not necessary true for all lowercase website text.